# How to access new neo4j ubuntu/ec2 install?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I installed neo4j on ec2 and started the service. If I `curl http://localhost:7474` from within the remote shell, it returns something positive:

`{
  "management" : "http://localhost:7474/db/manage/",
  "data" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/",
  "bolt" : "bolt://localhost:7687"
}`

I opened port 7474 in the security group of my ec2 instance.

However when I try to access http://ec2-52-3-253-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474/ in my browser, the site can't be reached.

Is there a step I am missing to expose the neo4j service to the public on ec2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how does Neo4j run on ec2, but try setting this two setting in neo4j.conf, to allow non-local connections and maybe set an advertised address.

```
# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a 
non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This 
may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the 
server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you, uncommenting this single line, then restarting neo4js did it: dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

Comment: In my case the line `dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost` was uncommented by default. But all worked as exepected, thanks for the answer